# Records in single JSON file is different , how can i handle this type of issue in ADF

Tags: json, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have one attribute name shipment in the JSON file there are 100 records total in one file.

In some records shipment is in this format  `"shipment":[ ]`

while in some records  shipment is in this format

`"shipment": { "id": 171700, "order_print_process_id": 170541 }`

so I need to flatten the file in ADF. is this possible to handle this type of problem in Azure data factory using the data flow activity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have taken the following sample data and used azure dataflow to achieve the requirement.

```
[
    {
        "sid":"A1",
        "shipment":[171701,170541]
    },
    {
        "sid":"B1",
        "shipment":{ "id": 171600, "order_print_process_id": 170640 } 
    },
    {
        "sid":"A2",
        "shipment":[171702,170542]
    },
    {
        "sid":"B2",
        "shipment":{ "id": 171601, "order_print_process_id": 170641 } 
    }

]
```

- Take this JSON file as source in the dataflow. The projection would make the shipment record as a string (as its value can be either an array or object). Use a conditional split on this data with the following condition:

```
startsWith(shipment,'{')
```

[image]

- The stream `shipmentObject` has shipment whose value is object and `shipmentArray` has shipment whose value is array.
- Now on the result of `shipmentObject`, use a derived column transformation. Take the shipment column and use `regexExtract` function in the following way to get the `id` and `order_print_process_id`.

```
array(regexExtract(shipment,'(\\d+),"order_print_process_id":(\\d+)}',1),regexExtract(shipment,'(\\d+),"order_print_process_id":(\\d+)}',2))
```

[image]

- Similarly use derived column transformation on `shipmentArray` with the following dynamic content:

```
array(regexExtract(shipment,'(\\d+),(\\d+)',1),regexExtract(shipment,'(\\d+),(\\d+)',2))
```

[image]

- Use union transformation to combine both the streams.

[image]

- Now use another derived column transformation to create separate columns as `shipment_id and shipment_order_print_process_id` in the following way.

[image]

- The final data would be as shown in the below image:

[image]

- The following the complete dataflow JSON:

```
{
    "name": "dataflow2",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Json1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "split1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "getArrayFromStringArray"
                },
                {
                    "name": "getArrayFromStringObject"
                },
                {
                    "name": "union1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          sid as string,",
                "          shipment as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     documentForm: 'arrayOfDocuments') ~> source1",
                "source1 split(startsWith(shipment,'{'),",
                "     disjoint: false) ~> split1@(shipmentObject, shipmentArray)",
                "split1@shipmentArray derive(shipment = array(regexExtract(shipment,'(\\\\d+),(\\\\d+)',1),regexExtract(shipment,'(\\\\d+),(\\\\d+)',2))) ~> getArrayFromStringArray",
                "split1@shipmentObject derive(shipment = array(regexExtract(shipment,'(\\\\d+),\"order_print_process_id\":(\\\\d+)}',1),regexExtract(shipment,'(\\\\d+),\"order_print_process_id\":(\\\\d+)}',2))) ~> getArrayFromStringObject",
                "getArrayFromStringObject, getArrayFromStringArray union(byName: true)~> union1",
                "union1 derive(shipment_id = shipment[1],",
                "          shipment_order_print_process_id = shipment[2]) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 sink(validateSchema: false,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     store: 'cache',",
                "     format: 'inline',",
                "     output: false,",
                "     saveOrder: 1,",
                "     mapColumn(",
                "          sid,",
                "          shipment_id,",
                "          shipment_order_print_process_id",
                "     )) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```